# Displaying image from Javascript to Processing.js canvas

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

So, I'm trying to programmatically add an image to my canvas, from a Javascript function :

```
    // Spawn function
    var spawnWrapper = function() {
        myCanvas = Processing.getInstanceById('mycanvas');
        // myCanvas.ellipse(50,50,50,50); // works fine here too
        myImage = myCanvas.loadImage('pegman.png');
        myCanvas.image(myImage,0,0);
    };
```

The same successive calls in console works :
[image]
Also, there are no errors mentioned on the console.

I'm really stuck there and would appreciate any help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you might be missing the [preload directive](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/).

> This directive regulates image preloading, which is required when
>   using loadImage() or requestImage() in a sketch. Using this directive
>   will preload all images indicated between quotes, and comma separated
>   if multiple images are used, so that they will be ready for use when
>   the sketch begins running.

I hope that helps. I'm curious as to why you're using processing.js instead of [P5.js](https://p5js.org/)?

Good luck.

Comment: Actually, you're right about everything. I've first used processing.js instead of P5.js because this is the one I've used for learning. Btw, looking further, I found P5.js which is waaay easier to integrate with JS and also spotted the preload directive for me... Thx !